# How to forward from one java servlet to another in same session

Tags: java, servlets, forward

So rather simple question, with quite few answers online, but I've tried them all and none of them seem to work for me.

```
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("Home");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

This is my current attempt , which produces `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I've also tried using  `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Home");` 
Which produces a blank page

```
response.sendRedirect("Home");
```

Works but doesn't preserve same session

I am redirecting from my Login servlet to Home servlet, both are stored in same package, both are in web.xml ( even if that is no longer needed)

Comment: Since you want to pass from Login servlet to Home servlet, just do a redirect, that should work. What's the exact problem you have with this approach? Make sure that you store data in session scope and not in request scope.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza my user details are stored in beans, which cant be in request scope, but with redirect my user gets reset to null, as if there isnt one, Ok I got redirect to work by storing user directly in session, but I am not sure if that's a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted my problem by storing username directly in session instead of beans, and used redirect instead of forward, for some reason beans werent properly retaining values after redirect.